# Elasticsearch - How to translate this simple SQL query to elastic search request

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, syntax, filter, elastica

I need to translate simple SQL like this:
`WHERE (abc1 IN (x, y, z) OR abc2 IN (x, y, z) OR abc3 IN (x, y, z)) AND (abc4 IN (x, y, z) OR abc5 IN (x, y, z)) AND abc6 < 5 AND abc7 IN (x, y, z)`
into elasticsearch query.

I made a query (posted below) that looks like it's doing what I need it to do but I'm unable to create `AND (abc4 IN (x, y, z) OR abc5 IN (x, y, z)` part in the first () of SQL. I've been getting elasticsearch errors or no results with countless variations of this request JSON while trying to get it to work. I think that the right answer would be to use filtered query with `"and"` key but I am unable to find the correct variation.

Can someone please help me? I am loosing my hope, while trying to solve this problem for about a week. Or can you pleasae at least tell me if I am on the right direction to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "abc1": [x, y, z]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "abc2": [x, y, z]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "abc3": [x, y, z]
                    }
                },
            ]
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "abc7": [x, y, z]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "nestedpath",
                        "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                    "nestedpath.abc6": {
                                        "lt": 5
                                    }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Something like this should be a match:

```
"_source": {
    "group": {
        "abc1": "x",
        "abc2": "y",
        "abc3": "z"
    },
    "anotherGroup": {
        "abc4": "y",
        "abc5": "z"
    },
    "nestedpath": [
        {
            "abc6": 2
        }
    ],
    "abc7": "x"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping is like that:

```
{
  "test7" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type3" : {
        "properties" : {
          "abc7" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "anothergroup" : {
            "properties" : {
              "abc4" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "abc5" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "group" : {
            "properties" : {
              "abc1" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "abc2" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "abc3" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "nestedpath" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "abc6" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will match what you want:

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "bool":{
                        "should":[
                           {
                              "terms":{
                                 "group.abc1":[
                                    "x",
                                    "y",
                                    "z"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "terms":{
                                 "group.abc2":[
                                    "x",
                                    "y",
                                    "z"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "terms":{
                                 "group.abc3":[
                                    "x",
                                    "y",
                                    "z"
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "bool":{
                        "should":[
                           {
                              "terms":{
                                 "anothergroup.abc4":[
                                    "x",
                                    "y",
                                    "z"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "terms":{
                                 "anothergroup.abc5":[
                                    "x",
                                    "y",
                                    "z"
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "nested":{
                        "path":"nestedpath",
                        "query":{
                           "bool":{
                              "must":{
                                 "range":{
                                    "nestedpath.abc6":{
                                       "lt":5
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms":{
                        "abc7":[
                           "x",
                           "y",
                           "z"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know as soon as possible (in about 10 hours from now). It looks like something I haven't tried so far.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. It does not throw any error but I get 0 results back which is wrong.

I get results if I remove this part
    {
        "bool":{
        "should":[
            {
                "terms":{
                    "abc4":[
                    "x",
                    "y",
                    "z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "terms":{
                    "abc5":[
                    "x",
                    "y",
                    "z"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
        }
    }

Comment: Can you give an example document that will match your requested query?

Comment: Yes, I think that the problem is that some fields are "nested" inside an object group. Something like this would be a match:

"_source": {
    "group": {
        "abc1": "x",
        "abc2": "y",
        "abc3": "z"
    },
    "anothergroup": {
        "abc4": "y",
        "abc5": "z"
    },
    "nestedpath": [
        {
            "abc6": 2
        }
    ],
    "abc7": "x"
}

I'll edit my original post to include formated sample document.

Comment: Can you please share the mapping too?

Comment: Probably not but I can try. I just use the search service, I am not the server adminsitrator. When I create request like GET /indexname/typename/_mapping/field/abc7 i get back 404. Maybe it is disabled? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: So do you know which fields are actually nested? If the only abc6 is in nested field you need to add group prefix for abc1-2-3 like group.abc1 etc and anothergroup prefix for abc4-5 like anothergroup.abc4. If these fields also nested you need to add nested query format for these too as for abc6.

Comment: Yes, only field abc6 is trully nested and abc1, abc2, abc3 is in a group as well as abc4 and abc5 in an another group. All other fields are 1st level keys like abc7 identical to sample match I have posted. I can match it like group.abc1 or anothergroup.abc4 but I cannot match them both at the same time. If I try nested query for group or anothergroup i get following error "[nested] nested object under path [group] is not of nested type". The problem is probably in joining OR sql statement of 1st and 2nd group since when I remove one of them I get results back.

Comment: I checked it and it looks the same as what it tried this morning. I have tested it again but it does not return anything (0 hits) and does not throw any error. I am not the system administrator so I can't judge mapping but to me it also looks exactly like what I am working with.

Comment: I created an index with that mapping and inserted the document you provide and running the query matched it. Without exact mapping i cant halp anymore sorry

Comment: That's strange but I understand. Thank you for your help. I'll try some more combinations and also try to get exact mapping structure or at least some information about it from system administrator. It's strange that it works for you but does not return anything for me. The query is constructed to match more than 100k records in a big database and it returns data until I connect that part AND (abc4 IN (x, y, z) OR abc5 IN (x, y, z)) translated from SQL. Anyway thanks again for you help, at least I have general direction I should be aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST /_xpack/sql/translate, 
U can run sql on ES, and U can translate sql to ES query
See:[https://www.elastic.co/blog/an-introduction-to-elasticsearch-sql-with-practical-examples-part-1]